# ERROR: Could not resolve Vercel deployment with Remix

Tags: reactjs, build, vercel, remix.run

I am new to web dev, and I'm trying to deploy my first application. I am using the git integration with Vercel, nice and easy. However it fails to run the remix-build command, commenting the following errors:

```
[11:32:22.674] Running build in San Francisco, USA (West) – sfo1
[11:32:22.731] Cloning github.com/minimuscle/foodmap (Branch: main, Commit: 4765904)
[11:32:22.737] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[11:32:23.646] Cloning completed: 915.238ms
[11:32:23.769] Running "vercel build"
[11:32:24.219] Vercel CLI 28.16.4
[11:32:24.874] Warning: Detected "engines": { "node": ">=14" } in your `package.json` that will automatically upgrade when a new major Node.js Version is released. Learn More: http://vercel.link/node-version
[11:32:24.877] Installing dependencies...
[11:32:25.184] yarn install v1.22.17
[11:32:25.267] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[11:32:25.270] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[11:32:29.269] warning @remix-run/dev > cacache > @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
[11:32:29.693] warning @remix-run/dev > @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill > rollup-plugin-node-polyfills > rollup-plugin-inject@3.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-inject.
[11:32:30.278] warning @remix-run/dev > @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill > rollup-plugin-node-polyfills > rollup-plugin-inject > magic-string > sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
[11:32:31.444] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[11:32:44.859] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[11:32:44.862] warning " > @react-leaflet/core@2.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "leaflet@^1.9.0".
[11:32:44.863] warning " > @remix-run/vercel@1.13.0" has unmet peer dependency "@vercel/node@^1.8.3 || ^2.4.0".
[11:32:44.869] warning "@remix-run/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[11:32:55.698] [5/5] Building fresh packages...
[11:32:56.135] success Saved lockfile.
[11:32:56.139] Done in 30.96s.
[11:32:57.169] Running "yarn run build"
[11:32:57.351] yarn run v1.22.17
[11:32:57.385] $ remix build
[11:32:58.323] Building Remix app in production mode...
[11:32:59.064] 
[11:32:59.067] [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react"[0m
[11:32:59.067] 
[11:32:59.067]     app/components/MapComponent.jsx:1:43:
[11:32:59.068] [37m      1 │ import React, { useEffect, useState } from [32m"react"[37m
[11:32:59.068]         ╵                                            [32m~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.068] 
[11:32:59.068]   You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.068] 
[11:32:59.068]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "google-map-react"[0m
[11:32:59.068] 
[11:32:59.068]     app/components/MapComponent.jsx:2:27:
[11:32:59.068] [37m      2 │ import GoogleMapReact from [32m"google-map-react"[37m
[11:32:59.068]         ╵                            [32m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.068] 
[11:32:59.068]   You can mark the path "google-map-react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.068] 
[11:32:59.069]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"[0m
[11:32:59.069] 
[11:32:59.069]     app/components/MapComponent.jsx:51:8:
[11:32:59.069] [37m      51 │         [32m[37m<button hidden={hide}>{text}</button>
[11:32:59.069]          ╵         [32m^[0m
[11:32:59.069] 
[11:32:59.069]   You can mark the path "react/jsx-runtime" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.069] 
[11:32:59.069]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"[0m
[11:32:59.070] 
[11:32:59.070]     app/components/Sidebar.jsx:4:6:
[11:32:59.070] [37m      4 │       [32m[37m<h1>Sidebar</h1>
[11:32:59.070]         ╵       [32m^[0m
[11:32:59.070] 
[11:32:59.070]   You can mark the path "react/jsx-runtime" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.070] 
[11:32:59.070]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "@remix-run/react"[0m
[11:32:59.070] 
[11:32:59.070]     app/entry.client.jsx:1:29:
[11:32:59.070] [37m      1 │ import { RemixBrowser } from [32m'@remix-run/react'[37m
[11:32:59.071]         ╵                              [32m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.071] 
[11:32:59.071]   You can mark the path "@remix-run/react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.071] 
[11:32:59.071]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react"[0m
[11:32:59.071] 
[11:32:59.071]     app/entry.client.jsx:2:44:
[11:32:59.071] [37m      2 │ import { startTransition, StrictMode } from [32m'react'[37m
[11:32:59.071]         ╵                                             [32m~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.071] 
[11:32:59.071]   You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.071] 
[11:32:59.072]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react-dom/client"[0m
[11:32:59.072] 
[11:32:59.072]     app/entry.client.jsx:3:28:
[11:32:59.072] [37m      3 │ import { hydrateRoot } from [32m'react-dom/client'[37m
[11:32:59.072]         ╵                             [32m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.073] 
[11:32:59.073]   You can mark the path "react-dom/client" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.073] 
[11:32:59.073]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"[0m
[11:32:59.073] 
[11:32:59.073]     app/entry.client.jsx:7:26:
[11:32:59.073] [37m      7 │     hydrateRoot(document, [32m[37m<RemixBrowser />)
[11:32:59.074]         ╵                           [32m^[0m
[11:32:59.074] 
[11:32:59.074]   You can mark the path "react/jsx-runtime" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.074] 
[11:32:59.074]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "@remix-run/react"[0m
[11:32:59.074] 
[11:32:59.074]     app/root.jsx:8:7:
[11:32:59.074] [37m      8 │ } from [32m'@remix-run/react'[37m
[11:32:59.074]         ╵        [32m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.075] 
[11:32:59.075]   You can mark the path "@remix-run/react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.075] 
[11:32:59.075]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"[0m
[11:32:59.075] 
[11:32:59.075]     app/root.jsx:19:6:
[11:32:59.075] [37m      19 │       [32m[37m<head>
[11:32:59.075]          ╵       [32m^[0m
[11:32:59.075] 
[11:32:59.076]   You can mark the path "react/jsx-runtime" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.076] 
[11:32:59.076]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "@remix-run/react"[0m
[11:32:59.076] 
[11:32:59.076]     app/routes/index.jsx:1:21:
[11:32:59.076] [37m      1 │ import { Link } from [32m'@remix-run/react'[37m
[11:32:59.076]         ╵                      [32m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.076] 
[11:32:59.076]   You can mark the path "@remix-run/react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.076] 
[11:32:59.076]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"[0m
[11:32:59.076] 
[11:32:59.076]     app/routes/index.jsx:5:4:
[11:32:59.076] [37m      5 │     [32m[37m<div>
[11:32:59.077]         ╵     [32m^[0m
[11:32:59.077] 
[11:32:59.077]   You can mark the path "react/jsx-runtime" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.077] 
[11:32:59.077]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "@remix-run/react"[0m
[11:32:59.077] 
[11:32:59.077]     app/routes/map.jsx:1:36:
[11:32:59.077] [37m      1 │ import { Link, useLoaderData } from [32m"@remix-run/react"[37m
[11:32:59.077]         ╵                                     [32m~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.077] 
[11:32:59.077]   You can mark the path "@remix-run/react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.077] 
[11:32:59.077]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react"[0m
[11:32:59.078] 
[11:32:59.078]     app/routes/map.jsx:2:25:
[11:32:59.078] [37m      2 │ import { Suspense } from [32m"react"[37m
[11:32:59.078]         ╵                          [32m~~~~~~~[0m
[11:32:59.078] 
[11:32:59.078]   You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.078] 
[11:32:59.078]  [31m✘ [41;31m[[41;97mERROR[41;31m][0m [1mCould not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"[0m
[11:32:59.078] 
[11:32:59.078]     app/routes/map.jsx:10:4:
[11:32:59.078] [37m      10 │     [32m[37m<div className='map'>
[11:32:59.079]          ╵     [32m^[0m
[11:32:59.079] 
[11:32:59.079]   You can mark the path "react/jsx-runtime" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.
[11:32:59.079] 
[11:32:59.079] 
[11:32:59.080] Build failed with 15 errors:
[11:32:59.080] app/components/MapComponent.jsx:1:43: ERROR: Could not resolve "react"
[11:32:59.080] app/components/MapComponent.jsx:2:27: ERROR: Could not resolve "google-map-react"
[11:32:59.080] app/components/MapComponent.jsx:51:8: ERROR: Could not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"
[11:32:59.081] app/components/Sidebar.jsx:4:6: ERROR: Could not resolve "react/jsx-runtime"
[11:32:59.081] app/entry.client.jsx:1:29: ERROR: Could not resolve "@remix-run/react"
[11:32:59.081] ...
[11:32:59.081] Error
[11:32:59.081]     at Object.onCompileFailure (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli/commands.js:182:13)
[11:32:59.081]     at Object.compile (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/compiler/remixCompiler.js:34:134)
[11:32:59.081]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[11:32:59.081]     at async Object.build (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/compiler/build.js:33:3)
[11:32:59.081]     at async Object.build (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli/commands.js:177:3)
[11:32:59.082]     at async Object.run (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli/run.js:449:7)
[11:32:59.101] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[11:32:59.101] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[11:32:59.119] Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
[11:32:59.360]
```

I don't understand why it is not resolving "react". In local, remix builds fine and I have no issue, so it seems its something to do with vercel. I can't see anyone else with this issue either.

Comment: I ended up switching to npm from yarn. I believe it has something to do with yarn's plug and play (PNP). It may just be yarn itself with remix not entirely sure, but fresh install from npm fixed my issue, saying with npm and I haven't had this error reoccur.